# OnTextChanged se retrasa para ocultar validadores

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Hola buen día tengan todos, estoy realizando un programa usando asp .net y c#, el código siguiente son mis controles de apellidos dentro del formulario, sucede que cuando se ingresa al menos un apellido, automáticamente se deben de poner en enable=false y visible=false los validadores de

```
RequiredFieldValidator y RegularExpressionValidator
```

el evento realiza lo que quiero pero el problema que tengo es que tarda demasiado en quitar los validadores de los controles, aproximadamente 8 segundos, cuando debería ser inmediato.

No soy muy avanzado en desarrollo, si de favor pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería.

```
  protected void txtApellido1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtApellido1.Text)|| !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtApellido2.Text))
            {
                rfvtxtApellido1.Enabled = rfvtxtApellido1.Visible = false;
                rfvtxtApellido2.Enabled = rfvtxtApellido2.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                rfvtxtApellido1.Enabled = rfvtxtApellido1.Visible = true;
                rfvtxtApellido2.Enabled = rfvtxtApellido2.Visible = true;
            }

        }

        protected void txtApellido2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtApellido2.Text)|| !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtApellido1.Text))
            {
                rfvtxtApellido1.Enabled = rfvtxtApellido1.Visible = false;
                rfvtxtApellido2.Enabled = rfvtxtApellido2.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                rfvtxtApellido1.Enabled = rfvtxtApellido1.Visible = true;
                rfvtxtApellido2.Enabled = rfvtxtApellido2.Visible = true;
            }

        }
```

```
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div id="idRegistros" runat="server" style="display: none;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                       <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Style="margin-bottom: 5px" Width="100%">Primer apellido</asp:Label>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtApellido1" placeholder="Ingresa apellido" Width="100%" CssClass="form-control input-group-sm" Style="text-align: center !important;" Height="39px" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtApellido1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="revtxtApellido1" ValidationGroup="guardar" ControlToValidate="txtApellido1" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,30}$" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic">
                                                <div class="alert alert-warning d-flex align-items-center" role="alert">
                                                    <div>
                                                        **El apellido no debe exceder de 30 caracteres
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvtxtApellido1" ValidationGroup="guardar" CssClass="colorErrorValidator" ControlToValidate="txtApellido1" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic">
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger d-flex align-items-center" role="alert">
                                                 <div>
                                                   Se requiere mínimo un apellido
                                                 </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Style="margin-bottom: 5px" Width="100%">Segundo apellido(s)</asp:Label>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtApellido2" placeholder="Ingresa apellido" Width="100%" CssClass="form-control input-group-sm" Style="text-align: center !important;" Height="39px" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtApellido2_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="revtxtApellido2" ValidationGroup="guardar" ControlToValidate="txtApellido2" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,30}$" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic">
                                              <div class="alert alert-warning d-flex align-items-center" role="alert">
                                                  <div>
                                                      **El apellido no debe exceder de 30 caracteres
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" Enabled="false" ID="rfvtxtApellido2" ValidationGroup="guardar" CssClass="colorErrorValidator" ControlToValidate="txtApellido2" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic">
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger d-flex align-items-center" role="alert">
                                                    <div>
                                                        Se requiere mínimo un apellido
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    

                                    </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Anteriormente estaba sin updatepanel, pero tardaba más, en cuanto agregue updatepanel mejoró.